# Seagate SSHD drive dual boot dilemma

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I've got a question regarding dual boot using Seagate SSHDs.

My computer specs are:

- MoBo: AsRock 980DE3/U3S3
- CPU: AMD FX-6300 3,5 GHz 64-bit Non-Overclocked
- GPU: AMD Radeon R7 360 Sapphire Nitro
- RAM: 8 GB
- SSHD: Seagate 1TB SSHD (8 GB SSD cache)
- PSU: 500W some no-name, I think.
- OS: Windows 10 Home OEM 64-bit

Computer is custom built, I don't think I've got Secure Boot there (Checked via Windows PowerShell).

I want to dual boot Windows 10 with Ubuntu 14.04.0 or 16.04. My partitions are:

- C: 390 GB
- D: 196 GB (Empty)
- E: 343 GB (Empty)
- 500 MB System Reserved

All partitions are NTFS ones. So here are my questions: Is Ubuntu Seagate SSHD compatible? Can I install Ubuntu on E: partition safely and still be able to boot Windows?

If yes:

I suspect most of the Windows 10 system files are in the SSD cache. Will installing Ubuntu harm them? Or move them to HDD? Will reformatting E: to ext4 harm Windows and/or its activation? And on which partition would I have to install GRUB to cover both Linux and Windows? Which version of Ubuntu (from these 2 mentioned by me) will work better with my computer?

I really thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can format or delete the empty partitions however you like. Windows doesn't care because nothing of importance to Windows is on there (they're empty after all).

The cache integrated into your hybrid (solid state and hard disk) drives is either (1) inactive or (2) transparent which means that Ubuntu will (1) either not touch it unless told otherwise or (2) not be aware of it and the disk controller will just manage the cache without knowledge of or importance to the operating system of the hour.